# Elastic search update-by-query how work with date field (parse from string?)

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new in elastic and I need work with date in update-by-query script.

I have docs with field **expire** which is mapped as **date**.

I try in my script in update-by-query:

```
SimpleDateFormat expire = new SimpleDateFormat(\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z\", Locale.getDefault());
long expireTime = expire.parse(ctx._source.expire).getTime();
```

But there is error: **Unparseable date: "2017-07-21T11:19:42+02:00"**

Is there a different way, how got date object or UNIX timestamp?

Or is there a way how got mapped formats instead of strings in update-by-query?

Thank you.

Comment: I think there shouldn't be any space between `ss` and `Z`

Comment: I tried a lot of modifications, without space too, but still return "Unparseable date".

Comment: Can you simply try this instead `long expireTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(ctx._source.expire).toInstant().toEpochMilli()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some documentation on [working with dates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/7.13/painless-datetime.html#_datetime_parsing_and_formatting) in scripts. Just do this and it will work:

```
long expireTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(ctx._source.expire).toInstant().toEpochMilli()
```